# C++ fstream object can't write after read a character

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream f("a.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    char s;
    f >> s;
    f << s << endl;
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to read a char from a.txt, then write it into a.txt. But after reading, the char can't be wrote in the file.

[the character in a.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wqWd.png)

Comment: I compiled your code and the output was `abcda`

Comment: You might want to check 1) that your file has read and write permissions, 2) whether it contain hidden characters